# Clone React componenet with different properties/states

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking to clone an react component that uses the same 'mechanism' as the original component, that doesn't depend on it. Here's my componenet, a small counter (I'm new to react, trying my best to learn it)

```
 class BreakCount extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
    this.state = {init: props.init}
    this.drop = this.drop.bind(this)
    this.add = this.add.bind(this)
  }

  drop() {
    if(this.state.init > 1) {
      this.setState ({
      init: this.state.init - 1
    });
    }
  }

  add() {
    this.setState({
      init: this.state.init + 1
    })
  }


  render() { 
    return (<div id = 'bc'>
      <button onClick={this.drop}>-</button>
       <button>{this.state.init}</button>
       <button onClick = {this.add}>+</button>
      </div>)
  }
}
```

If u didn't understand, think about something that does the same thing, but has different states. I can rewrite the new component as the original one, but I don't think that's the right way to do it..

Comment: I think you can write new component that **extends** your component and overload some methods you want to behave differently

Comment: @Ivan Shmidt I can rewrite it from 0, but that's not the way I'm looking for..

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to do. `React.cloneElement` it may help you.

Comment: @ The Reason Does it work with class componenets as well ?

Answer (score 0):

setting props to state values are bad practise in React. The more elegant way to use your component with different **props**, all you need to is to pass the props and manage your components without state (except for common data). According to this, If you want to clone the element, you can use :

```
React.cloneElement(element, {prop1: "a", prop2: "b", ...})
```

or just use your component with different props as :

```
<Element prop1="a" prop2="b" />
<Element prop1="c" prop2="d" />
```

In this case, you need to set up a store (for example redux, react-redux, etc.) at top of your component hierarchy, and anything you intend to change in state should change it inside store which will lead your root component re-render and pass the new props into your child component(s).

Comment: I'll see what  I can do.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to reuse that component severalTimes with different props. here is an example:

```
import BreakCount from './breakCount.jsx'; 
export default class ParentClass extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <BreakCount init={3}/>
                <BreakCount init={1}/>
                <BreakCount init={200}/>
            </div>
        );
    }     }
```

add export to your breakCount class:

```
export default class BreakCount extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
    this.state = {init: props.init}
    this.drop = this.drop.bind(this)
    this.add = this.add.bind(this)
  }

  drop() {
    if(this.state.init > 1) {
      this.setState ({
      init: this.state.init - 1
    });
    }
  }

  add() {
    this.setState({
      init: this.state.init + 1
    })
  }


  render() { 
    return (<div id = 'bc'>
      <button onClick={this.drop}>-</button>
       <button>{this.state.init}</button>
       <button onClick = {this.add}>+</button>
      </div>)
  }
}
```